# Confusion related to the cross-validated deviance of lasso fit

Tags: generalized-linear-model, matlab, lasso

I am having some confusion relating to cross-validated deviance of a lasso fit. I am not sure what is being done.

Let's say I run lassoglm in Matlab for my dataset having 1000 examples and 15 features with a CV of let's say 100. What does it do?

And what does the plot lassoPlot with CV do?

I am referring to [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso-regularization-of-generalized-linear-models.html#btcoa3h)

I didn't understand what "deviance" means. Can anyone explain, please?

Comment: Since you're fitting GLMs, the [deviance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_%28statistics%29) for GLMs would be the relevant thing.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MATLAB's help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lassoglm.html), deviance is the value of the loss function for the type of model that you are using. It is the value of negative log-likelihood (MSE for linear regression) for your model averaged over the validation folds in the cross-validation procedure.